# How to identify a user type and redirect them each to a different page when they log in?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I currently have a pretty standard login function inside my UsersController, and it currently just redirects anyone to my products page when they log in. How do I do something like `if($this->$user = 'consumer') //redirect to consumer products`

Here's my current login function

```
public function login(){

        if($this->request->is('post')) {

            if ($this->Auth->login()){
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect(
                    array('controller' => 'Products', 'action' => 'index')));
            }

            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Incorrect username or password.'));
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using cakephp AuthComponent, it will allow you to access to the different user fields using

```
$this->Auth->user('User.fieldname');
```

Let's say that i have the field 'type' where the type of the user will be saved !

```
switch ($this->Auth->user('User.type')){
  case 'customer':
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'products','action'=>'index'));
  break;
  case 'super_admin':
    $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'administration','action'=>'index'));
  break;
  default:
    $this->Auth->logout();
  break;
}
```

hope it helped you.